# Double integral problem with use of transformation of variables

Tags: integration

By suitable transformation of variables x and y to another pair of variables, calculate
the integral

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^{2}}{({\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1})^5}dxdy $

I just don't know what do they mean by suitable transformation and how to start the problem.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1\right)^5}\space\text{d}x\right)\space\text{d}y=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform to polar coordinates: $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta.$

Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^{2}}{({\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1})^5}dxdy = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{r^2 \cos^2 \theta}{({r+1})^5}rdr d \theta \\= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta \, d \theta \int_{0}^\infty \frac{r^3}{({r+1})^5}\, dr \\= \pi \cdot \frac1{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but could you tell me how did you work out the limits of integration?

Comment: @Cornvaly: You are integrating over the entire plane.  The disk $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi, 0 \leqslant r \leqslant R$ covers the plane as $R \to \infty$.  Think of this improper integral as the limit of the integral over the disk as $r \to \infty$.